# ERROR: Unhandled exception: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'FLAGS')

Tags: javascript, discord, bots

please fix it its a discord bot antiswear.js code its sad i cant  fix it , i have to exclude admins from antiswear module of  bot but its not working properly tho -

```
const { Permissions } = require('discord.js');
const badWords = require('@src/badwords.json');

const warnedMessages = new Set();

function checkMessage(message) {
  const content = message.content.toLowerCase();

  if (message.member && message.member.permissions && message.member.permissions.has(Permissions.FLAGS.ADMINISTRATOR, true)) {
    return; // Skip moderation actions for administrators
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure `Permissions` is the correct thing to be importing? Your error means its `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided any detail about what version you're on, so I'll assume v14. Let me know if the below doesn't work, and I'll do my best to research with your version of Discord.JS.

According to the [Permissions Guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/permissions.html#checking-member-permissions) you need to use the `PermissionsBitField` class slightly differently, like so:

Line one:

```js
// You've imported the wrong class. Try PermissionsBitField instead!
const { PermissionsBitField } = require('discord.js');
```

Line nine:

```js
// Use the .Flags.Administrator property instead of the same in upper case
  if (message.member && message.member.permissions && message.member.permissions.has(PermissionsBitField.Flags.Administrator, true)) {
```

[Docs for PermissionsBitField](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/PermissionsBitField?scrollTo=s-Flags) and [Docs for PermissionsFlagsBits](https://discord-api-types.dev/api/discord-api-types-payloads/common#PermissionFlagsBits)

Happy coding!